# Java nio Files: readAllBytes vs readAllLines ? Which to use when?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to understand the best practices related to these two methods of the Java nio Files class:

[readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)) vs [readAllBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path))

Which to use when ? Most results from google return a way to use them, but doesn't touch upon when to use one over the other.

Can someone please help me understand ?

Comment: Do you want an array of bytes or do you want Strings?  Do you want undifferentiated bytes or do you want to process line-wise?  First you decide what you intend to use the data for, and then the choice should be obvious.

Comment: The obvious choices are already understood. Hence, asking for `best practices`

Comment: There is no "best practices" here. It depends what's in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `readAllLines` documentation (emphasis my own):

> Read all lines from a file. **Bytes from the file are decoded into
> characters using the UTF-8 charset.**

So right off the bat, you are told that `readAllLines` will automatically decode strings through the UTF-8 character set. This means that at the very least, you shouldn't use it when you are **NOT** dealing with the UTF-8 charset, but rather you have files stored in UTF-16 or UTF-32 (or some other, non UTF-8 character set).

Also, you don't always deal with strings, sometimes you are dealing with:

- Binary data, which could be read and deserialized into some other object.
- Image data.

So from my viewpoint, `readAllLines` is basically a `readAllBytes` with some extra processing on top of it (to transform bytes into a list of strings).

Comment: There's a readAllLines that allows you to choose the charset.  But the crux of the matter remains the same -- is this text to be processed a line at a time, or is this non-text data?

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: Thanks for the clear concise explanation! I understand the scenario when non-UTF-8 string data are concerned. However, could you also touch upon any differences if we are just dealing with a UTF-8 text file/data ?

Comment: @user14644949: Agreed, other overloads of this method just wrap around the same methods. I wouldn't be surprised that the `readAllLines` method just calls one of these overload with a *hard coded* `UTF-8` value as a character set.

Comment: @Somjit: If you are dealing with text files stored with the `UTF-8` character set, then you would probably go with using the `readAllLines`, since it provides you with what you already need, so you do not go about re-inventing the wheel.